# Programmatic manipulating with chart elements in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, data-visualization

When I hover the mouse above the chart elements, it can show some standard hints. How can I show the tooltips without hovering? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showAllDataTips` property of `ChartBase` class should get you what you want.